# VTK: Frontfaces rendered as see-through

Tags: java, opacity, vtk

I have a set of points and faces that I'm rendering using java and vtk. I want solid faces, however, the frontfaces end up being rendered as see-through.

Turning on FrontfaceCulling removes all see-through faces but that's not what I want.

Here's some dummy code that draws a cube instead but displays the same problem:

```
import vtk.*;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import vtk.vtkNativeLibrary;

class Cube {
    int x, y, z;
    vtkRenderer renderer;

    Cube(vtkRenderer renderer, int x, int y, int z) {
        this.renderer = renderer;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;

        render();
    }

    private void render() {
        vtkUnstructuredGrid grid = new vtkUnstructuredGrid();

        vtkPoints points = new vtkPoints();
        grid.SetPoints(points);

        points.InsertPoint(0, x, y, z);
        points.InsertPoint(1, x+1, y, z);
        points.InsertPoint(2, x+1, y+1, z);
        points.InsertPoint(3, x, y+1, z);

        points.InsertPoint(4, x, y, z+1);
        points.InsertPoint(5, x+1, y, z+1);
        points.InsertPoint(6, x+1, y+1, z+1);
        points.InsertPoint(7, x, y+1, z+1);


        vtkCell q1 = new vtkQuad();
        vtkIdList l1 = q1.GetPointIds();
        l1.SetId(0, 3);
        l1.SetId(1, 2);
        l1.SetId(2, 1);
        l1.SetId(3, 0);
        grid.InsertNextCell(q1.GetCellType(), l1);

        vtkQuad q2 = new vtkQuad();
        vtkIdList l2 = q2.GetPointIds();
        l2.SetId(0, 7);
        l2.SetId(1, 6);
        l2.SetId(2, 5);
        l2.SetId(3, 4);
        grid.InsertNextCell(q2.GetCellType(), l2);

        vtkQuad q3 = new vtkQuad();
        vtkIdList l3 = q3.GetPointIds();
        l3.SetId(0, 0);
        l3.SetId(1, 4);
        l3.SetId(2, 7);
        l3.SetId(3, 3);
        grid.InsertNextCell(q3.GetCellType(), l3);

        vtkQuad q4 = new vtkQuad();
        vtkIdList l4 = q4.GetPointIds();
        l4.SetId(0, 1);
        l4.SetId(1, 2);
        l4.SetId(2, 6);
        l4.SetId(3, 5);
        grid.InsertNextCell(q4.GetCellType(), l4);

        vtkQuad q5 = new vtkQuad();
        vtkIdList l5 = q5.GetPointIds();
        l5.SetId(0, 0);
        l5.SetId(1, 1);
        l5.SetId(2, 5);
        l5.SetId(3, 4);
        grid.InsertNextCell(q5.GetCellType(), l5);

        vtkQuad q6 = new vtkQuad();
        vtkIdList l6 = q6.GetPointIds();
        l6.SetId(0, 3);
        l6.SetId(1, 7);
        l6.SetId(2, 6);
        l6.SetId(3, 2);
        grid.InsertNextCell(q6.GetCellType(), l6);


        vtkDataSetMapper mapper = new vtkDataSetMapper();
        mapper.SetInputData(grid);

        vtkActor actor = new vtkActor();
        actor.GetProperty().SetColor(0.4, 0.9, 0.2);
        actor.SetMapper(mapper);

        vtkCamera camera = renderer.GetActiveCamera();
        camera.Azimuth(30);
        camera.Elevation(20);

        renderer.AddActor(actor);
    }
}


public class SimpleVTK extends JPanel {

    static {
        for (vtkNativeLibrary lib : vtkNativeLibrary.values()) {
             try {  
                 System.loadLibrary(lib.GetLibraryName());
             } catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
             }
         }
     }


    public SimpleVTK() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        final vtkRenderWindowPanel renderWindow = new vtkRenderWindowPanel();
        renderWindow.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        renderWindow.setInteractorStyle(new vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera());

        vtkRenderer renderer = new vtkRenderer();
        renderWindow.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(renderer);

        new Cube(renderer, 0, 0, 0);

        renderer.ResetCamera();
        renderer.SetBackground(0.0, 0.0, 0.2);

        add(renderWindow, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleVTK");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.getContentPane().add(new SimpleVTK(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```